# Binary subtraction in Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to make a binary calculator that subtracts two binary numbers (only with base 2) without parsing it.

Can anyone help me with the situation that I have zero in the upper number and one in the lower number, I can't seem to write the code for it.

```
for (int i = ss.length()-1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)=='0' && ss.charAt(i)=='0') sb.append("0");
            else if (s.charAt(i)=='1' && ss.charAt(i)=='0') sb.append("1");
            else if (s.charAt(i)=='1' && ss.charAt(i)=='1') sb.append("0");
            else
            {
                sb.append("1");
                doit(s,i+1,sb);
            }
        }

        for (int i = s.length() - ss.length(); i >-1; i--) 
        {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }

        ArrayList<Character> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =  sb.length()-1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            res.add(sb.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    public static void doit(StringBuilder s, int i, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > -1; j--)
        {
            if(s.charAt(j)=='0')
            {
                s.setCharAt(j, '1');
            }
            else
            {
                s.setCharAt(j, '0');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code that you tried? And what do you mean by : - `binary numbers (only with base 2)`? Binary numbers are base 2 only right? Why explicit mentioning?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Can you define `without parsing`? I can't tell you to subtract two numbers, but not give you permission to read them.

Comment: I guess "without parsing" means, 'in character representation of "0" and "1".' Anyway, there's an ambiguity in the assignment: which binary system. A common one is 2's Complement ( http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binary_numbers ), which gives you the rules, such as 00000 - 1 = 11111 (or 111111, or 11111 + integer overflow :)) . Just implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it strictly bitwise, right to left, like at least some chips do. The tricky knowledge is a five-column table: (a,b, carry bit from prior position) -> (result, new carry bit). You don't actually borrow from the higher-level positions; you carry the underverflow into those instead. See table 2.4 here:

http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vpWS-s4d5vMC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=binary+subtraction+table+carry&source=bl&ots=458JWgZl8v&sig=sjuXedv96KCbNWmxQAPNQo7iuRw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i-6jUI7IB8jusgay8IDQDQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=binary%20subtraction%20table%20carrysubtract&f=false

Define two methods: (a,b, carry bit from prior position) -> result and (a,b, carry bit from prior position) -> new carry bit, and apply them right to left.

---

Alternative: invert your second argument according to the rules here: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binary_numbers .

Then add #1 to the inverted #2 :).

PS. Who said it's a bad assignment :)?

Answer (score 2):

Binary rules of subtraction.

```
1 - 1 = 0
0 - 0 = 0
1 - 0 = 1
0 - 1 = 1 (needs a carry bit from a higher bit position.  
    You might have to check several higher bits before you 
    find the carry bit.  -1 otherwise.)
```

Comment: Hard to find out: too convoluted, too procedural. Would require debugging/nitpicking. I'd better redo it using a more structured approach. See my answer. You do it right going right to left. At each step, use two simple methods that map (a, b, carry) to a-b and new carry, respectively. The methods are easy to write: for each of 8 combinations of (a, b, carry) return the output bit. And your code will magically get clear and, chances are, will work right away. Or you'll be able to debug it easily. Try it!

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class binary_diff
{
    public String diff(String st1,String st2)
    {
        String nst="",max="";char b='0';boolean tf=(st1.length()>=st2.length());
        int l1=st1.length(),l2=st2.length();
        if(l1<l2)
        for(int a=1;a<=l2-l1;a++)
        st1='0'+st1;

        else if(l2<l1)
        for(int a=1;a<=l1-l2;a++)
        st2="0"+st2;
        if(!tf)for(int a=l1-1;a>=0;a--)
        if(st1.charAt(a)!=st2.charAt(a))
        if(st2.charAt(a)=='1'){max=st2;st2=st1;st1=max;break;}

        for(int a=st1.length()-1;a>=0;a--)
        {
            if(st1.charAt(a)=='1' && st2.charAt(a)=='0')
            {
                if(b=='1')
                {nst='0'+nst;b='0';}
                else
                nst='1'+nst;
            }

            else if(st1.charAt(a)==st2.charAt(a) && st2.charAt(a)=='1')
            {
                if(b=='1')
               {nst='1'+nst;b='1';}
                else
                nst='0'+nst;
            }

            else if(st1.charAt(a)=='0' && st2.charAt(a)=='1')
            {
                if(b=='1')
                nst='0'+nst;
                else
                {nst='1'+nst;b='1';}
            }

            else
            {
                if(b=='1')
                nst='1'+nst;
                else
                nst='0'+nst;
            }
        }
        return nst;
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers");
        String s1=sc.next();
        String s2=sc.next();
        binary_diff bd=new binary_diff();
    System.out.println(bd.diff(s1,s2));
    }
}
```